# How can i reuse the selected item outside the ui-select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

i am using the ui-select and would like to use the selected item outside the ui-select control. I tried using {{$select.selected.name}} but this did not work. I want to reuse it in an ng-repeats filter.

Comment: A jsfiddle link would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I have used

```
<ui-select ng-model="listOfCategoryTypes.ID" ...
```

When i use {{listOfCategoryTypes.ID}} outside the ui-select it give the JSON Object. When i extend

```
{{listOfCategoryTypes.ID.Name}}
```

with .Name (i have a property called Name), then i get the properties value!